# Highcharts map gradients to y-axis?

Tags: javascript, css, graph, highcharts

I'm trying to get the gradients to map to my y-axis. I have a min of 90 and a max of 150. I want a yellow gradient from the top down to 120 and I want it to be consistent across browsers. Can I do this? Here's my code:

```
 $('#ao_vs_ppv').highcharts({
                            chart: {
                                    backgroundColor: 
                                    {
                                            linearGradient: [0, 215, 0, 220],
                                            stops: [
                                                    [0, 'rgb(255,255,50)'],
                                                    [1, 'rgb(255,255,255)']
                                            ]
                                    },
                                    type: 'scatter'
                            },
                            title: {
                                    text: 'Air Overpressure Vs. Peak Particle Velocity'
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                    min: .010,
                                    max: 10,
                                    type: 'logarithmic',
                                    title: {
                                            text: "Peak Particle Velocuty (in/sec)"
                                    },
                                    labels: {
                                            overflow: 'justify'                 
                                    },
                                    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                                    gridLineWidth: 1
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                    min: 90,
                                    max: 150,
                                    title: {
                                            text: 'Air Overpressure (dBL)'
                                    },
                                    tickInterval:10,
                                    labels: {
                                            overflow: 'justify'                         
                                    }
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                    scatter: {

                                            tooltip: {
                                                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                                                    pointFormat: 'AO: {point.y}dBL<br>PPV: {point.x}in/sec'
                                            }
                                    }
                            },
                            legend: {
                                    layout: 'horizontal',
                                    borderWidth: 1,
                                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                                    shadow: true
                            },
                            series:formatHighChartsScatter(data[i]['x_data'],data[i]['y_data'], seismoNames)
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from `backgroundColor` to `plotBackgroundColor`, and use object format, not pixel, see: http://jsfiddle.net/92Nw8/1/

```
$('#ao_vs_ppv').highcharts({
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: {
        linearGradient: {
            x1: 0,
            x2: 0,
            y1: 1,
            y2: 0
        },
        stops: [
            [0, 'rgb(255,255,50)'],
            [1, 'rgb(255,255,255)']
        ]
    },
    type: 'scatter'
  }
}
```